# Unity Netcode: Change Ownership doesn't work for me

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity-networking

I have been trying to spawn gameObject(Specifically Player gameObject) in Server using this **player.GetComponent().Spawn()** and then tried to change ownership. It didn't works for me. So frustrated. Can anyone help on this.

I want to spawn two different player in server and client. So I tried to spawn all the players in server only and tried to change the ownership using ownerclientId, LocalClientId. Nothing worked. What happens is that it spawns two players in both server and client screen but only server has the ownership.

Code snippet:

```
private void Start()
    {
        var playerSelected = GameObject.Find("PlayerSelected");
        int selectedPlayer = playerSelected.GetComponent<PlayerSelected>().selectPlayer;
        if (NetworkManager.Singleton.IsServer)
        {
            PlayerSpawner(selectedPlayer, OwnerClientId);
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerSpawnerOnServerRpc(selectedPlayer, OwnerClientId);
        }
    }

    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    void PlayerSpawnerOnServerRpc(int selectedPlayer, ulong clientId)
    {
        PlayerSpawner(selectedPlayer, clientId);
    }

    void PlayerSpawner(int selectedPlayer, ulong clientId)
    {
         GameObject player;
         switch(selectedPlayer)
         {
             case 0:
                    player = Instantiate(player1Prefab, spawnPositionPlayer1);
                    player.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn();
                    player.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().ChangeOwnership(clientId);
                    break;
             case 1:
                    player = Instantiate(player2Prefab, spawnPositionPlayer2);
                    player.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn();
                    player.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().ChangeOwnership(clientId);
                    break;
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason this doesn't work is that the server is sending two messages in quick succession.

```cs
player.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn();
player.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().ChangeOwnership(clientId);
```

The first tells the clients to spawn an object. The second gives ownership to the object. You cannot guarantee (even running locally) that the `Spawn()` has finished when the `ChangeOwnership()` is called. So when `ChangeOwnership()` is called, the client may not have finished initialising the object that's spawned.

Unity were aware of this, and provided you with `SpawnWithOwnership` ([docs](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/basics/networkobject#ownership)). Replace your two lines with one:

```cs
player.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().SpawnWithOwnership(clientId);
```

Comment: And you can get the clientid from the ServerRpcParams `
public void SomeServerRpc(ServerRpcParams serverRpcParams = default) {  var clientId = serverRpcParams.Receive.SenderClientId; }`